Laptop becomes too hot when power is plugged on
Not longer than a month ago, I've updated my 23.10 (with kernel update?) and several things broke on my Lenovo ideapad laptop:

When power cable is plugged in, and I watch any video, CPU temperature jumps from 50s to 70s Celsius despite fans speeding up. When powered from battery, the same video watching routine does not cause noticeable temperature bump.
When I close the lid, KDE no longer puts system to sleep, despite this being enabled
I have both AMD and Nvidia cards, with only the latter supporting HDMI - it got reset to AMD and I had to change it back.

I've since updated to 24.04 but the issue is still there. I'm not sure how to diagnoze it. CPU utilization does not grow when power is plugged in. powertop does not show any changes to CPU usage patterns.
In general, how do I diagnoze power consumption / power saving events such as lid closing, etc? Any obvious ways to see current power consumption status of CPU and change it?

Check your fan. Is it spinning, blocked, or dusty? Is there dust coating your chips? Dust is a very good insulator.  Overheating is a hardware problem, not fixable by software.

Why nothing overheats without the power cable being plugged in? The same video will play without any lag and with basically the same CPU use, and the CPU will stay cold unless on AC power.
